# Using BeautifulSoup to extract the title of a link

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract the title of a link using BeautifulSoup. The code that I'm working with is as follows:

```
url = "http://www.example.com"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal'}):
    title = link.get('title')
    print title
```

Now, an example `link` element contains the following:

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal" href="http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Computation-Programming-Using-Python/dp/8120348664" title="Introduction To Computation And Programming Using Python"><h2 class="a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">Introduction To Computation And Programming Using <strong>Python</strong></h2></a>
```

However, nothing gets displayed after I run the above code. How can I extract the value stored inside the `title` attribute of the anchor tag stored in `link`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it seems you have put two spaces between `s-access-detail-page` and `a-text-normal`, which in turn, is not able to find any matching link. Try with correct number of spaces, then printing number of links found. Also, you can print the tag itself - `print link`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=python"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal'})
print len(links)
for link in links:
    title = link.get('title')
    print title
```

Comment: `print link` outputs the above `link` value that I mentioned in my original post. The class name is indeed correct and is able to find matching links. But I can't seem to extract the value inside the `title` attribute from `link`.

Comment: Please try replacing the `.text` with `.content`, i.e., `plain_text = source_code.content`. Also, could you post a sample url?

Comment: This is the URL I'm working with: `http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=python`

Comment: The links with class is not there in the html source of the page.

Comment: Try inspecting the elements which contain the titles of the books.

Comment: I just edited my answer, and the above code is working perfectly fine. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for an *exact string* here, by using multiple classes. In that case the class string has to match *exactly*, with single spaces.

See the [*Searching by CSS class* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) in the documentation:

> You can also search for the exact string value of the class attribute:
>
> ```
> css_soup.find_all("p", class_="body strikeout")
> # [<p class="body strikeout"></p>]
> ```
>
> But searching for variants of the string value won’t work:
>
> ```
> css_soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout body")
> # []
> ```

You'd have a better time searching for individual classes:

```
soup.find_all('a', class_='a-link-normal')
```

If you *must* match more than one class, use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('a.a-link-normal.s-access-detail-page.a-text-normal')
```

and it won't matter in what order you list the classes.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> plain_text = u'<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal" href="http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Computation-Programming-Using-Python/dp/8120348664" title="Introduction To Computation And Programming Using Python"><h2 class="a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">Introduction To Computation And Programming Using <strong>Python</strong></h2></a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
>>> for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='a-link-normal'):
...     print link.text
... 
Introduction To Computation And Programming Using Python
>>> for link in soup.select('a.a-link-normal.s-access-detail-page.a-text-normal'):
...     print link.text
... 
Introduction To Computation And Programming Using Python
```