# Get the title of a link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

As the title says, I am trying to get the title of a link, that is located inside of a cell. [This is](http://theescapists.gamepedia.com/Crafting) the website I am getting my stuff from. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542549/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-title-of-a-link) question, which is where I got my last couple lines of code from, but it didn't quite finish it for me

I am trying to get the title of the link inside the first column (or first cell of each row). I can get *all* of the HTML code in the cell, but I am having troubles nailing down obtaining just the title. This is what I've come up with so far

```
URL = 'http://theescapists.gamepedia.com/Crafting'
get_page = requests.get(URL)
plain_text = get_page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')


for table_tag in soup.find_all('table'):
    for each_row in table_tag.find_all('tr'):
        links = each_row.find('a', href=True)
        title = links.get('title')
        print(title)
        print('')
```

If I print just the `links` section, all of the code within each cell gets printed.

I am getting an error that says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` when I print the `title` part, which confuses me because I've done `print(type(links)) and I get a`bs4.element.Tag`back, which makes me think I should be able to look through for a`title` tag.

As a recap (this seemed a little long), I want to get the title tag from the *first cell* of each link in each table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` tag can contains `th` tag which do not has `a` tag, you should check the `a` tag before you access it:

```
In [100]: for table_tag in soup.find_all('table'):
     ...:     for each_row in table_tag.find_all('tr'):
     ...:         links = each_row.find('a', href=True)
     ...:         if links: # check before you access
     ...:             title = links.get('title')
     ...:             print(title)
     ...:             print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `links.attrs['title']` is what you want.

My code:

```
for table_tag in soup.find_all('table'):
    for each_row in table_tag.find_all('tr'):
        links = each_row.find('a', href=True)
        try:
            title = links.attrs['title']
            print(title)
            print('')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Note: The `AttributeError` is going to handle the header of the table, which doesn't have a `title`.