# How can I get title name in <a href=' ' title = ' '></a> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

for example,

```
<a href="wiki..." title="example"> blah </a>
title = soup.select('div > ul > li > a') # ???
```

I want to get title name "example" in [ a href=' ' title=' ' ].

If possible, I would like to use 'select' sentence.

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542549/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-title-of-a-link/32542575#32542575

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BeautifulSoup to extract the title of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542549/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-title-of-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, to get the title from a link, you can do this:

```
# if you have a link extracted
link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'whatever the class name is'})

# then you can do this to get the title
title = link.get('title')
```